# How to make a Choropleth Density Map using dataset with Spatial Point data

Tags: r, spatial, density-plot

I have a dataset which contains points data in the form of longitude and latitude from across the UK.

I am trying to create a Choropleth density map to show the density of points within geographic boundaries (e.g. OA, MSOA) or as a grid on top of the UK.

I have look but been unsuccessful in finding any methods of doing this.

Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: Please provide the coding you´ve already done, and ask for a more specific problem than `how can this be done`. This site is no code-writing service!

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41514105/4752675) may help.